Colors are more blue on the gpu then on the cpu
When I change the render device from the CPU to the GPU it gets more green/blue. Is there any way to fix this. Could this also be a Linux issue because I don't think I've seen this on windows.


It might be helpful if you post an image of your render settings.

It may be normal behavior, CPU and GPU computations being different. Here is one of multiple bug reports I was able to find, in which devs stated that it's not considered a bug and expected behavior. It appears the choice between CPU and GPU is quite important. https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/101561
